# Suppress "does not implement protocol" warning in GCC

Tags: xcode, gcc, warnings, pragma

I want to suppress a particular warning while developing an iPhone app in Xcode. The warning is:

```
"warning: class 'XXX' does not implement the 'XYZ' protocol"
```

I understand I use the directive:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

But I don't know what the xxxxxxxxxxxx should be. Any ideas?

(Assumption: there is a valid reason for doing this. And I need to do this because otherwise I can't enable the treat warnings as errors option.)

Comment: I have since found the name is -Wno-protocol, but then I get the "unknown option after #pragms GCC diagnostic kind".

Comment: Don't suppress that warning. If the warning appears, you have done something wrong, and need to fix it.

Comment: Jonathan, please read the assumption. I'm asking a specific question and I'm sure that the question "Should I supress this warning...?" is elsewhere on SO.

Comment: I also need this. In my case, I'm passing OCHamcrest matchers as arguments to mocked methods.

Comment: I think your example should read:
`#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol"`

Or I suppose they're probably equivalent...  however this does not work for me on GCC/LLVM 4.2.1 and I notice that using `-fdiagnostics-show-option` does not list a `-Wxxxxxxx` parameter for that protocol warning (or the similar 'does not conform to' warning).  Maybe a future version of GCC will...  there seems to be push/pop support for these diagnostics now. (I too, am getting warnings re: OCHamcrest + mocks).

Comment: Actually, I just realised that casting to `(id)` supresses the "does not conform to protocol" warning in my test: `[[controllerSpy expect] setCategoryViewController:(id)allOf(instanceOf([UIViewController class]), conformsToProtocol(@protocol(SMAcceptsCategory)), nil)];`

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is just that you can't use `-Werror` then use `-Wno-protocol` to disable that particular warning. Not all warnings can be disabled by pragmas.

Answer (score -3):

Try this.

```
@interface XXX: UIViewController < XYZ>
{
```

}

Comment: How does that suppress a GCC warning? In the original question I was looking for the flag, in the revised part (see comment) I had found the flag but then I had another error.